# Why does Subclipse requires me to cleanup when I want to checkout a new project?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I was working on a specific project using **eclipse-kepller** and **subclipse**.
Recently the SVN was upgraded and the URL and moved to a new server. Now when I try to checkout the project (as a new project) I get the following:

> **"Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted"**

I ran cleanup on the project (connected to old SVN) but - no change.
Nothing I try seems to work: upgraded the subclipse, tried to checkout any other existing project -failed, switched to another user, downloaded a new eclipse.

Note: some files are still checked out on the old server.
Any ideas are welcome - I'm clueless here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out - working with the interface of JavaHL cause my problems.
Once I switched to **SVN Kit** - problem solved.

In eclipse: Team -> SVN -> SVN Interface